# How to make a MFC Visual Studio C++ program use both CPUs in a dual processor setup

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I recently built a workstation with a dual Xeon E5-2699v4 CPUs. This provides me with a total of 88 threads. I have a program that can benefit from using these threads. However when I tested it out, it seemed that it was only utilising 1 processor in the setup. Trying to use more than 44 threads, would cause the system to have momentary lockups. 
The program uses MFC Visual Studio C++. What would need to be done to code the program to use both processors?

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/products/91317/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2699-v4-55M-Cache-2_20-GHz
Why do processors exist with this many cores!?!

Comment: This xeon has 22 cores which gives 44 threads each, two of them gives 88 threads, e.g. virtual cpus

Comment: Even without similar hardware, someone might review your code and identify some issue or another.  But probably no one can help you without providing some minimal code to review.

Answer (score 2):

> What would need to be done to code the program to use both processors?

You need to understand how the code is spending the cpu-cycles, i.e. benchmark. Read on about simple method duration versus context-switch duration.

---

"C++ has no notion of cores".  Thus, the idea of associating a thread with a particular core is delegated to the operating system (in which the program is executing), and I have not seen the C++ language semantics for the issue.  I have read of os calls to associate a thread with a core, but I have never grokked why, nor experimented.

On Ubuntu, I simply start the threads, and rely on the OS (Linux) to assign each running thread to an available processor resource.  Linux seems to do a reasonable job.

I have measure two threads to perform the 'same' comparison work on two independent data's to cut the duration in half, and both cores are often fully utilized.  (small to no i/o actions mixed in)

---

Contexts switches are about an order of magnitude slower than method invocations.  So perhaps your code design should avoid switching.

Or, perhaps it is an effort of balance, code granularity, i.e. how much code to finish for each switch.

On my Ubuntu 17.10 system I have measured the combined duration of '::sem_wait()' and '::sem_post()' (both small methods) to about 31 ns (103.7 M events in 3,237,099 us), [with no context switches, of course].

On my 2 core processor, one of my tests runs 10 threads for 10 seconds, and does not force a context switch, leaving a single critical section for the thread-to-thread interaction.  I was surprised that the same thread often runs multiple times before one of the 'starving' threads gets to run (it is not a problem on that 'Linux minor benchmark' - lmbm).  The code reports 297 ns per context switch.  (33 M switches in 10 secs, 297 ns per).

When I enforce a 'balanced-sharing-of-cores' (by using two semaphores per thread), every thread runs as often as any other.  The switch duration is quite a bit longer (but not available to me at this moment).

---

I don't have the opportunity to measure 10 threads on 44 cores, it sounds like fun.  I estimate the range of performance would be 'big' - perhaps from "stalled" to "10x" the duration of 1 thread. Depending not on which core the code runs on, but on what the code does when it runs.